# Is there a way to sort a JSON object without reordering arrays inside it?

Tags: json, sorting

I want to sort the JSON without reordering the arrays. The JSON looks like:

```
{  
   "objectid":"589a399724bd631d0424265a",
   "mappingerrors":[  

   ],
   "timestamp":"UCT",
   "models":[  
      {  
         "models4":"589a399724bd631d01234567",
         "models1":"AAAA",
         "models3":"244",
         "models5":"7ee92c958a051e66f19d6561575c5642",
         "models2":"01945610",
         "values":[  
            {  
               "11":"YYYY",
               "1":"A",
               "9":"B",
               "5":"XXXX",
               "3":2,
               "10":239.804,
               "6":"C",
               "2":"D",
               "4":"2017-02-03T21:53Z",
               "8":"MSFT",
               "7":"TTTT"
            }
         ],
         "models6":"2017-02-03T21:53Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to sort this to the below:

```
{  
   "mappingerrors":[  

   ],
   "models":[  
      {  
         "models1":"AAAA",
         "models2":"01945610",
         "models3":"244",
         "models4":"589a399724bd631d01234567",
         "models5":"7ee92c958a051e66f19d6561575c5642",
         "models6":"2017-02-03T21:53Z",
         "values":[  
            {  
               "1":"A",
               "2":"D",
               "3":"2",
               "4":"2017-02-03T21:53Z",
               "5":"XXXX",
               "6":"C",
               "7":"TTTT",
               "8":"MSFT",
               "9":"B",
               "10":"239.804",
               "11":"YYYY"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "objectid":"589a399724bd631d0424265a",
   "timestamp":"UCT"
}
```

I tried with the following code, but it's not giving the appropriate result.

```
function sortObject(jsonObject) {
        var sorted = {},
            key, a = [];

        for (key in jsonObject) {
            if (jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                a.push(key);
            }
        }

        a.sort();

        for (key = 0; key < a.length; key++) {
            sorted[a[key]] = jsonObject[a[key]];
        }
        return sorted;
    }
```

Is there any way to do it by ignoring the arrays inside a JSON object?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Objects in JSON are not ordered structures, why do you want to "sort" them at all? Also *"not giving the appropriate result"* isn't a [mcve].

Comment: The textual representation of JSON makes an illusion to you that they imply ordering on object's key. In both JavaScript object and JSON specification state clear that they are **unordered** [RFC7159](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt)

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to sort/order keys in JavaScript objects?](/questions/9658690/)

Comment: Also related: [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](/a/23202095/43452)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to order the arrays.

```js
var unordered = {
  "objectid": "589a399724bd631d0424265a",
  "mappingerrors": [

  ],
  "timestamp": "UCT",
  "models": [{
    "models4": "589a399724bd631d01234567",
    "models1": "AAAA",
    "models3": "244",
    "models5": "7ee92c958a051e66f19d6561575c5642",
    "models2": "01945610",
    "values": [{
      "11": "YYYY",
      "1": "A",
      "9": "B",
      "5": "XXXX",
      "3": 2,
      "10": 239.804,
      "6": "C",
      "2": "D",
      "4": "2017-02-03T21:53Z",
      "8": "MSFT",
      "7": "TTTT"
    }],
    "models6": "2017-02-03T21:53Z"
  }]
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(unordered));

var ordered = unordered;
var modelsOrder = {};
var valuesOrder = {};
Object.keys(unordered.models[0]).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  modelsOrder[key] = unordered.models[0][key];
});

Object.keys(unordered.models[0].values).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  valuesOrder[key] = unordered.models[0].values[key];
});

ordered.models[0] = modelsOrder;
ordered.models[0].values = valuesOrder;
console.log(JSON.stringify(ordered));
```

You can run the code snippet and verify.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks anoop, it helped, just needed to modify the values part, function _sortJson(unordered) {
    var ordered = unordered;
    var modelsOrder = {};
    var valuesOrder = {};

    Object.keys(unordered.models[0]).sort().forEach(function (key) {
        modelsOrder[key] = unordered.models[0][key];
    });

    Object.keys(unordered.models[0].values[0]).sort().forEach(function (key) {
        valuesOrder[key] = unordered.models[0].values[0][key];
    });

    ordered.models[0] = modelsOrder;
    ordered.models[0].values[0] = valuesOrder;
    return JSON.stringify(ordered);
}